# Convert KeyDown keys to one string C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have magnetic card reader, It emulates Keyboard typing when user swipes card. I need to handle this keyboard typing to one string, when my WPF window is Focused. I can get this typed Key list, but I don't know how to convert them to one string.

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   list.Add(e.Key);
}
```

**EDIT**: Simple .ToString() method not helps. I've tried this already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than adding to a list why not build up the string:

```
private string input;

private bool shiftPressed;

private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.LeftShift || e.Key == Key.RightShift)
    {
        shiftPressed = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9)
        {
            // Number keys pressed so need to so special processing
            // also check if shift pressed
        }
        else
        {
            input += e.Key.ToString();
        }
    }
}

private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.LeftShift || e.Key == Key.RightShift)
    {
        shiftPressed = false;
    }
}
```

Obviously you need to reset `input` to `string.Empty` when you start the next transaction.

Comment: You can check if shift is pressed like this instead e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift) this way you wont need two events

Comment: Why not use stringbuilder instead of adding to a string?

Comment: @Preza8 - That would probably make more sense, but this was just meant to show the process rather than being a fully fledged solution.

Comment: @ChrisF Sorry, I meant to say that going from adding things to a list to concatenating strings seems to me like a change to the worse. Because the list does not do much but the string concatenation has to copy the previous string. So if you left it was it was, that would be that. But you already changed it.

Comment: @Preza8 the OP wants to change from using a list to using a string. Now I've revisited this again (after 9+ years) I'd probably suggest they keep a list then when the input has finished use `string.Join("", list)` to do the concatenation. Though that does depend on knowing when the input is complete.

Answer (score 2):

Listen To PreviewTextInput Event Instead ...
the TextCompositionEventArgs  has a property called "Text" which give you the text representation for key 
for example Key.D2 will be just "2" ...i think it will
do the purpose

```
private void MainWindow_OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
       list.Add(e.Text);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

...or you can try this:

```
string stringResult = "";
list.ForEach(x=>stringResult+=x.ToString());
```

EDIT:
After good Timur comment I decided to suggest this:

you can use keyPress event to everything like this:

```
string stringResult = "";
private void Window_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    stringResult += e.KeyChar;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't convert key to it's real value. For example I have "%" char, in e.Key value it will be "Left Shift" and "D5"

Answer (score 0):

You could have a member variable which is a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

something like

```
class A
{
    StringBuilder _contents = new StringBuilder();

    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        _contents.Append(e.Key.ToString());
    }
}
```

You would have to create a new StringBuilder each time a new card was swiped and then to get the string you would use _contents.ToString();

Comment: This solution is a great start, but codes like "D2" (which you get when you press the "2" keys) end up as "D2" rather than "2".

Answer (score -1):

String combined = String.Empty;

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   combined = combined + e.Key.ToString();
}
```

Comment: why don't you use `+=` ?

Comment: This is a good start, it certainly doesn't deserve downvotes.  However, it needs to additional logic to take into account how keyboard characters like the number "2" come through as a "D2".